# Order By clause using APEX Bind Variables in Geolocation SOQL gives GACK

Tags: soql, geolocation

So I was planning to use SOQL geolocation to fetch the nearest dealer to the location of our agent. To find nearest I am trying to use Order by clause along with geolocation. The SOQL is below

```
 List<Account> dealerShipAccount=   [SELECT id,name,Vienna_Legacy_Id__c FROM Account WHERE (RecordTypeId=:ACC_DEALRESHIP_RECORDTYPEID AND
                                DISTANCE(ShippingAddress,GEOLOCATION(:opp.GEOLOCATION__Latitude__s,:opp.GEOLOCATION__Longitude__s),'mi') < :radius ) 
                                ORDER BY DISTANCE(ShippingAddress,GEOLOCATION(:opp.GEOLOCATION__Latitude__s,:opp.GEOLOCATION__Longitude__s),'mi') 
                                LIMIT 1];
```

When I try to save it via Metadata/Tooling API or via SF Edit class UI I get GAcK.

> An internal server error has occurred An error has occurred while
>   processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been
>   notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional
>   information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the
>   error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of
>   the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well
>   as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using
>   salesforce.com!
>
> Error ID: 1358189510-219274 (-517776265)

When I remove the Order by clause the SOQL

```
List<Account> dealerShipAccount=    [SELECT id,name,Vienna_Legacy_Id__c FROM Account WHERE (RecordTypeId=:ACC_DEALRESHIP_RECORDTYPEID AND
                                    DISTANCE(ShippingAddress,GEOLOCATION(:opp.GEOLOCATION__Latitude__s,:opp.GEOLOCATION__Longitude__s),'mi') < :radius ) 
                                    LIMIT 1];
```

I cant find this in Known Issue section, can anyone throw some light whats wrong.

Comment: Have you try adding a n null check for Latitude fields in where clause?

Comment: Its compile time error, so I believe it should be irrelevant.

Comment: did you try to use an alias for the distance expression, not sure if it can be used in Order by though..

Comment: @Basti sorry mate, didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I raised a case with Salesforce and got the below response.

> We have heard back from R&D and Tier-3 .
>
> The issue is due a bug with old compiler , there is a workaround which
>   you could implement in your org .
>
> The workaround is instead of directly assigning sobject field paths to
>   the geolocation function, once assigning the field paths to single
>   reference local variables, pass them to the geolocation function, as
>   follows.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> public static void findNearbyDealers(Opportunity opp){ 
> double latitude = opp.GEOLOCATION__Latitude__s; 
> double longitude = :opp.GEOLOCATION__Longitude__s; 
> List dealerShipAccount=[Select id,name from Account where 
> DISTANCE(ShippingAddress,GEOLOCATION(:latitude, :longitude),'mi') < 20 
> order by DISTANCE(ShippingAddress,GEOLOCATION(:latitude, :longitude),'mi') 
> limit 1]; 
> } 
> }
> ```

I tried the solution provided by them, and it works charm.